# How do I respond to the "Maximum travel days/weeks" question on job application?

Tags: applications, travel

My situation is this - I'm trying to get into a large company. And on the job app. they ask the question:

```
Max. travel days/weeks
    No travel
    Up to 1 day a week
    Up to 2 day a week
    Up to 3 day a week 
    Up to 4 day a week
    Up to 5 day a week
```

I'm temped to answer 5 days, as it's the most flexible. And i'm still single.. but at the same time, would that mean I'm always flying and sipping red-bull, with no extra time ?

Would 2 days a week be seen as non-commital?

Comment: they are asking you in order to find out if your going to meet their needs.  I wouldn't recommend lying to them.  If there is no "as needed" option, then I don't think we can help you, sorry mate.

Comment: good point. turns out it worked out OK/ I agree, if you sign on it, thats it!

Comment: ...what?  Lol, i think you said it worked out just fine, in which case great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put what you are willing to do. Presumably when (if not before) they make an offer, they'll tell you what's involved, and you can say whether you are willing to take that or not.

Given that it's a large company, this is probably a standardized app, and the travel requirements will vary by job. Unless they are just taking random applications with no specific plans (not likely), they won't really pay much attention to this.

Comment: Ah, understood. Excellent  points! Thank You Very Much!